# Java, Failed to exec spawn helper error since moving to Java 14 on linux

Tags: java, java-11, java-14

Just moved from **Java 11** to **Java 14**

The following code is now failing on a linux machine:

```
String linux_exe  = System.getProperty("user.dir") + '/' + "fpcalc_arm32";
List<String> params = new ArrayList();
params.add(linux_exe);
params.add("-plain");
params.add("-length");
params.add(submittedSongLength);
params.add(file.getPath());
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(params.toArray(new String[1]));
```

with stacktrace

```
Cannot run program "/mnt/system/config/Apps/SongKong/songkong/fpcalc_arm32": error=0, Failed to exec spawn helper: pid: 13998, exit value: 127
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/mnt/system/config/Apps/SongKong/songkong/fpcalc_arm32": error=0, Failed to exec spawn helper: pid: 13998, exit value: 127
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:590)
at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:449)
at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.acoustid.AcoustId.generateFingerprint(AcoustId.java:217)
at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.acoustid.AcoustId.createAcoustIdFingerprint(AcoustId.java:106)
```

**What has changed in Java 14 that would cause this ?**

I ran the equivalent code on Windows using java 14 and that did run okay. But I had retried with same code base on this unix machine using both Java 11 and Java 14 and can confirm that **Java 11 always works** and **Java 14 always fails**

Comment: are you sure the same code was working with Java-11?

Comment: @Naman I think so, Im 100% sure working in Java 9 because that has beein production for 6months, I then moved upto Java 11 to fix a issue and never saw these fpcalc errors so I think it was fine, but because Java 11 did not fix original issue I am now trying Java 14, this does fix original issue, but now I am seeing the new issue reported here !

Comment: Not aware of the differences amongst the JDK you've mentioned in these terms. But, is the file read-protected by any means? Assuming the privileges of the user executing the program are the same across JDKs.

Comment: @Naman I have just rebuilt it to use Java 11 (not Java 14) and reran the same code on same machine and same file and now it is working fine, the only difference is if using jre11 works, if using jre14 doesnt work

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I have found the issue, I came across these issues on the Openjdk Bugs Database

[Provide a way for Runtime.exec to use posix_spawn on linux](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8212828)

and

[Change the Process launch mechanism default on Linux to be posix_spawn](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213192)

Essentially in *Java 11* Linux uses `vfork` to start processes but by *Java 13* it now uses `posix_spawn`.

`posix_spawn` actually requires a program called `jspawnhelper` that is located within `jre/lib`. In my case this exists but it does not have execute permissions, this is because I use `jlink` to build a jre that just has the system modules I need, but I create this on **Windows** (my main dev environment).

```
call "C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.6.10-hotspot\bin\jlink" --module-path="C:\Code\jthink\SongKong\linux_jdk\jmods"  --add-modules java.desktop,java.datatransfer,java.logging,java.management,java.naming,java.net.http,java.prefs,java.scripting,java.sql,jdk.management,jdk.unsupported,jdk.scripting.nashorn --output C:\code\jthink\songkong\linuxjre
```

Windows doesn't understand linux execute permissions, when I deploy my application I set execute permission on the executables that are in `jre/bin` but didn't know there were any executables in `jre/lib`. Changing the permissions on jspawnhelper to execute fixes the issue.

An alternative workaround is to add the following java option:

```
-Djdk.lang.Process.launchMechanism=vfork
```

Comment: Have you reported this to the Java developers? I think they'd be interested in hearing about this! (Even if the use case seems rather uncommon.) I think the [core-libs](https://mail.openjdk.org/mailman/listinfo/core-libs-dev) mail list is the right place. If you don't want to I will send a mail there.

Answer (score 8):

A rather exotic other reason for the same error message may be that the OS updated the java distribution while the program is running, and then the program tries to execute an external process. This happened to us on a deployed server, where the client updated the java distribution. The solution was to just restart the service.

Comment: Happened to me as well recently, service restart solved the issue.

Comment: This happened with our Jenkins setup as well. Service restart worked.