# Exception on running linux commands and shell scripts through Java

Tags: java, bash, exception

I am using this java method to make system calls to run linux commands and shell scripts:

```
public String executeShellCommand(String linuxCommand) {

        String commandOutput;
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder;
        String [] command = {
                "/bin/bash",
                "-c",
                linuxCommand
        };

        try {
            log.debug("Making system call : [{}]",String.join(" ", command));
            // Execute the shell command
            processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
            Process p = processBuilder.start();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            if ((commandOutput = br.readLine()) != null) {
                p.waitFor();
                log.trace("exit: " + p.exitValue());
                p.destroy();
                return commandOutput;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception in running shell command {}", linuxCommand, e);
        
            return null;
        }
       
        log.trace("There was no output for the given command {} that was executed", linuxCommand);
        return "";
    }
```

I keep getting the following exception every time the cron is scheduled to run the java process at every 6 hours (succeeds when JVM is executing the process but fails subsequently when scheduler runs it every 6 hours, even at the first scheduler run), but the funny thing is it succeeds when the cron is set to run every 15 or 30 minutes (tried running it for a 24 hours and succeeded all the runs of 30 mins):

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/bin/bash": error=0, Failed to exec spawn helper: pid: 2009, exit value: 127
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1143) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073) ~[na:na]
        at com.oracle.gbucs.database.exporter.provisioning.service.ShellCommandService.executeShellCommand(ShellCommandService.java:41) ~[classes!/:2024.2.6]
        at com.oracle.gbucs.database.exporter.provisioning.service.ProvisioningService.runExporterProvisioningScript(ProvisioningService.java:395) ~[classes!/:2024.2.6]
        at com.oracle.gbucs.database.exporter.provisioning.service.ProvisioningService.provisionExporterForOneDatabase(ProvisioningService.java:167) ~[classes!/:2024.2.6]
        at com.oracle.gbucs.database.exporter.provisioning.controller.ProvisioningController.provisionExporters(ProvisioningController.java:106) ~[classes!/:2024.2.6]
        at com.oracle.gbucs.database.exporter.provisioning.controller.ProvisioningController.scheduled(ProvisioningController.java:142) ~[classes!/:2024.2.6]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=0, Failed to exec spawn helper: pid: 2009, exit value: 127
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:314) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:244) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110) ~[na:na]
        ... 19 common frames omitted
```

An example of the linux command where it fails when run through Java but works fine when executed directly in command line:

Command to count number of scripts running currently on the server- `ps -ef | grep oracledb_exporter | grep -v grep | wc -l`

Java version is 17.0.5 and I am running this on a remote server (SSH session). I also did double check that I have bash on my server. What am I missing here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61325264/16034206 This is the result I find searching your stack trace. Take a look?

Comment: @BIBOOnation already went through most of these posts, tried vfork but didn't work! Thanks though

Comment: Have you verified where `jspawnhelper` is, checked that it is executable, and checked that the directory it is in is on the PATH of the JVM process?

Comment: @tgdavies jspawnhelper is executable but it's not on the PATH of the JVM process. Could that be causing this? But then how does it work when I run the java process every 15 or 30 mins through cron job? It should also fail then, right?

Comment: For what it’s worth, if your only task is counting the number of scripts, you can do the same thing without any external process:  `long count = ProcessHandle.allProcesses().filter(p -> p.info().command().filter(c -> c.contains("oracledb_exporter")).isPresent()).count();`

Comment: @VGR no, i also need to run shell scripts through my java code. But thanks!

Comment: The exception seems to be reporting that Java failed to execute `/bin/bash`.  Can you execute it directly?  For example, `/bin/bash --version`? There are several reasons why you (and Java) might not be able to do so.

Comment: That's failed to execute in the sense of "could not launch" not "exited with an error status".

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes i am able to do it directly in command line just fine.

Comment: To be clear: I don't mean just executing shell commands.  I mean running `/bin/bash` explicitly.  If you can do that as yourself but your Java program cannot do it, then, on Linux, one possibility to consider is that Java is being blocked by mandatory access controls (SELinux).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes I am able to run /bin/bash explicitly. But see that's the thing, it works whenever my java program is scheduled to run every 30 mins but fails when it's run every 6 hours. If there was something blocked, shouldn't it be failing at all times?

Comment: Probably so.  Which brings us around to the scheduler.  That whether the error occurs depends on the run interval with which the program is scheduled is very curious.  It suggests that either the scheduler is doing something different for those two intervals, or that there is some environmental timing-based  issue.  Can you provide some details about how you are scheduling it?  And when you schedule with a 6-hour interval, how soon does the first run occur?  Is it within 30 minutes?

Comment: This is my scheduleConfig cron interval: `schedule: '0 0 */6 * * *'`. So when it's scheduled at every 6 hours, the first run usually happens from main i.e. the JVM runs it when i first start the Java program and then at every 6 hours (UTC), the scheduler takes over.

Comment: Actually the JVM doesn't use the PATH to find jspawnhelper, it uses the `java.home` system property. You should log this and see that it is what you expect.